# Why uninstalling openjdk automatically triggers an installation of the alternatives on zypper openSUSE?

Tags: package-management, opensuse, java

I installed openSUSE 13.1 and I want to install Oracle jdk. What I intended was to first uninstall open_jdk/ice tea stuff as I won't be needing them anyway but it seems I cannot uninstall them without having other non-Oracle java packages installed.

```
us...r@linux-rvhj:/tmp/mc-junip> sudo zypper rm java-1_7*
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following 4 NEW packages are going to be installed:
  gcc48-gij gcc-gij java-1_5_0-gcj-compat libgcj48 

The following 3 packages are going to be REMOVED:
  icedtea-web java-1_7_0-openjdk java-1_7_0-openjdk-headless 

4 new packages to install, 3 to remove.
Overall download size: 9.3 MiB. After the operation, 25.8 MiB will be freed.
Continue? [y/n/p/? shows all options] (y):
```

How do I just uninstall packages without being forced any alternatives? And why zypper behaves like this? To prevent situation when dependencies of other packeges are removed?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer (I'm not an SUSE/zypper user), but it's a recommendation based on your description of your actual problem: "I want to install Oracle jdk. <s>What I intended was to first uninstall open_jdk/ice tea stuff</s>").

You don't *need* to uninstall ice tea, and this hassle w/ the package manager is the first indication that life will be easier if you *don't* uninstall it.  It does not do any harm to have both installed, and the system can be configured to prefer the Oracle version if that's what you want.  I'm presuming you're intending to use the package directly from Oracle and not some SUSE non-free repo (if there's such a thing).  Use the linux `tar.gz` package from Oracle (the one that's *not* marked "RPM"; note you need the "x64" one if your system is 64-bit), and follow the instructions for unpacking it.

You now need to put the `bin` directory in your executable path.  You can do this however you like, but a normative way to do this system wide is to add a `.sh` file to `/etc/profile.d` and

```
export PATH=/path_to_java/bin:$PATH
```

You'll have to log in again to make this effective, then double check w/ `echo $PATH`.  Directories at the beginning will take precedence, so anything that invokes `java` will now be invoking the Oracle version, and the package manager will be happy WRT things that require a JRE/JDK.

Comment: I came to a similar conclusion, but via a different route.  Not familar with zypper (my suse experience was blissfully short)

I think it's juggling dependencies, and that it's trying to satisfy something else -- that's why it's moving to install a similar suite when you pull out the other jdk.

I say leave it in for THAT reason, and maybe pull it out later once Oracle JDK is installed.  (sorry for the formatting and edits)